# How to enable Jira RPC Plugin in Jira trial version

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, testlink

I am trying to integrate Jira with TestLink. Found issue with enabling RPC plugin in JIRA. I am unable to find RPC Jira plugin in System settings. Where can we find RPC jira plugin in the Jira trial version?

Answer (score 1):

JIRA's SOAP and XML-RPC remote APIs were removed in JIRA 7.0 for Server ([see the announcement](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/latest-updates/soap-and-xml-rpc-api-deprecation-notice)).

In older versions of JIRA the RPC plugin should be active by default.

If you are using an older version, you should be able to find it under Administration -> Add-ons -> Manage add-ons.

Select "System" in the drop down menu to list all add-ons that ship with JIRA.

[image]

*(Screenshot from JIRA 6.4)*

Comment: Hi Gerald, thanks for your quick reply. I have followed your steps but no luck. I am using jira 7 version and could not find the rpc plugin in manage add-on->system

Comment: I edited my answer. The RPC interface has been removed in JIRA 7, it was already deprecated since version 6. Either you install an older version of JIRA or you find a different way to interface TestLink.